# HTML5 Validation for Grooveshark Widgets

Tags: validation, html, w3c-validation

I can't seem to find a way to fix the validation without breaking the widget.
My  element is missing 'data' and 'type' attributes.

Line 769, Column 38: Element object is missing one or more of the following attributes: data, type.

```
  <object width="250" height="40"> <param name="movie" value="http://listen…
```

I've added type="application/x-shockwave-flash" but that seems to break it too.

This is the full widget:

```
<object width="250" height="40"> <param name="movie" value="http://listen.grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" /> <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /> <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;widgetID=25014214&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0" /> <embed src="http://listen.grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="250" height="40" flashvars="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;widgetID=25014214&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0" allowScriptAccess="always" wmode="window" /></object>
```

You can see the widget in action here:
http://www.eportfolio.jameswmann.com

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
<object width="250" height="40" data="http://listen.grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf">
```

and drop

```
<param name="movie" value="http://listen.grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf" />
```